# регулярка 0-9 и один +

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Каким образом указать, что знак + может быть только один и только в начале строки?

```
preg_match('#^([+{1}0-9]*)$#ui', $_POST['tel'])
```

Comment: Вот так? `^(\+{1}[0-9]*)`

Comment: `var_dump( (bool) preg_match('~^(?:\+(?:7|38))?\d{10}$~', '+70503456789') );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри символьного класса большинство символов не являются специальными символами. Это касается и квантификаторов. `[+{1}]` находит `+`, `{`, `1` или `}`.

Чтобы шаблон `^([+{1}0-9]*)$` находил `+` только в начале строки, его необходимо вынести за скобки, удалить квантификатор `{1}` (это поведение по умолчанию) и экранировать его. Модификаторы `ui` тут не нужны, так как в шаблоне нет букв.

```
preg_match('#^(\+[0-9]*)?$#', $_POST['tel'])
```

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/U2xnvU/2)

Необязательная захватываемая группа `(...)?` добавлена для того, чтобы находилась также пустая строка (как в оригинальном случае).

Если знак `+` необязателен, добавьте квантификатор `?`:

```
preg_match('#^\+?[0-9]*$#', $_POST['tel'])
                ^
```

[См. демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/U2xnvU/1)